# my script prints the function without calling the function

Tags: python

So my assignment is this: "Using your knowledge of square roots in addition to standard double precision accuracy with your language, what is the square root of the sum of the first 10^5 square roots?

```
sqrt( sqrt(0) + sqrt(1) + sqrt(2) + ... + sqrt(99999) + sqrt(100000) )
```

Enter the number rounded to the nearest whole number

I've created a script:

```
from math import sqrt

def sumsqrt():
    return sqrt(sum(map(sqrt, range(100001))))

def main():
    print sumsqrt      

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

However, when I run this script in Terminal, this is the output:

```
mcbaby$ python cs28.py
<function sumsqrt at 0x652b0>
```

So I just decided to run Python in Terminal, and do it there. I did pretty much the same thing, except it worked.

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> sqrt(sum(map(sqrt, range(100001))))
4591.5148887832138
```

I was hoping somebody could help explain what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: The script wouldn't work in interactive Python at all.  Enter `print sumsqrt` at the `>>>` prompt and see what it does.  The title is very misleading.  Could you change it to something like "my script prints the function without calling the function" or something that describes the **real** problem.

Comment: Changed the title, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
print sumsqrt # print the address of the object in memory, similar to id(sumsqrt)
```

to

```
print sumsqrt()  # call the function and print what it returns.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you type in your `main` that snippet of code:

```
print sumsqrt
```

You are telling *print the "object" sumsqrt*.
And this is a *function*

Try to edit previous snippet in `print sumsqrt()`